# Creating Custom ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget, custom-component

I create a custom image view by extending ImageView that just draws some text on the screen, however I don't see anything painted in the Emulator Screen, but the log messages and the printlns get printed in the log console. Am I not doing something?

This is my activity

```
public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        CustomImageView myView = new CustomImageView(getApplicationContext());
        System.out.println("Setting the view");
        myView.invalidate();
        setContentView(myView);
        System.out.println("Calling invalidate");
    }
}
```

This is my CustomImageView

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView
{

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public CustomImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyle
     */
    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDraw(canvas);
        System.out.println("Painting content");
        Paint paint  = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(0x0);
        paint.setTextSize(12.0F);
        System.out.println("Drawing text");
        canvas.drawText("Hello World in custom view", 100, 100, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Hello Android", "Got a touch event: " + event.getAction());
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    }
}
```

Even the log message in the onTouchEvent() gets printed, but nothing is painted.

This is my main.xml that has the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<AbsoluteLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout">
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use color values **Color.WHITE** or **Color.BLACK** instead of hexa values.

Comment: @Ram - Only problem was the color values. We should use the Color class to generated color values.

Comment: Or use color hexa value in format 0xAARRGGBB.
white = 0xFFFFFFFF and black = 0xFF000000

Answer (score 1):

Have  you checked your canvas size? An image view expects the bitmap/drawable to return its size and based on the scaletype flags, determine the size of the view. I don't see anything in your code that determines the size of the view for layout needs.

-Rick