# nested button inside an image

Tags: android, xml, button

I try to put a regular button inside an image in android XML. How can it be done? I tried something like this:

```
<ImageView ....... 
          <Button .... />
</ImageView>
```

where the dots represent code. Apparently this is not the way because the platform threw an exception.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use relative layout to insert button on the image.

your image should be given in background tag of RelativeLayout.

```
   <RelativeLayout 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_nav"

                >

          <Button
            android:layout_width="63dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"

            android:id="@+id/mapbutton"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          />
```

this Example adds button on left side of the image since i used  layout_alignParentLeft="true"

Answer (score 3):

You can use FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/myImage"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <Button     android:id="@+id/myButton"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:text="My Button"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

You don't write why you need image and button. Do you know about ImageButton?

Answer (score 2):

@Uriel Frankel you may try creating a custom ImageView either.Here is a post regarding [Creating Custom ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470867/creating-custom-imageview).

Hope it helps.