# How Edit Image view in android

Tags: android

I have Image View I want to show the Current time and date on each Image View. I don't know how to edit the Image view in android.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this trick will help:

Take a textview and add your image as it's background and set it's text to current date and time whatever you want. :)

Yes you can do that using onDraw(Canvas c) which takes canvas parameter.[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) is also some functions of Canvas which can help you.

Comment: Thats a brilliant idea. And use padding and gravity to set the position of the text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But After Editing the Image I have to store that Image inside the SQL Lite Database. I am trying by using canvas Do you have any idea how to edit the Image by canvas.

Comment: @Mayu Thanks for the complement.Yes he/she can use the properties as u mentioned to put text properly according to his/her requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just override the `OnDraw` method and you will get the canvas parameter.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29)

Here is an example of someone overriding in this question:
[Creating Custom ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470867/creating-custom-imageview)

In order to save this to a database you will just need to save the canvas as a bitmap